# Host URL to print out some message on Java

Tags: java, url, heading

I'm trying to write data to /Users/brichards/message.html, but I'm unable to do so. I suspect the error may be involving the header of args[] (which is the host). I know the packet will need the host as the header, but I keep getting an error. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void SocketandURL(String[] args) throws Exception {


     
            String host = args[0];
            
            
            
            

            // Build and send a GET request packet. The packet is a String,
            // and therefore needs to be converted to a sequence of bytes before it
            // can be sent. There's a getBytes() method in the String class to do that.
            // The \r and \n characters are CR and LF. The first pair ends the GET line,
            // the second pair ends the "blank line" marking the end of the packet.
            // Any header info could have to be included before that blank line.

            String packet = "GET /wireshark-labs/INTRO-wireshark-file1.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
            packet = "Host: " + host + packet;
            

            System.out.println("Sending packet to " + host);
            
        try {
            // Read the resulting data and write it to our output file. We intentionally
            // use a DataInputStream rather than an InputStreamReader to get the data from
            // the socket, since we want to allow for reading binary data files like .jpgs,
            // but that means we need to convert it to a character string if we ever want
            // to print it out. This code uses a special constructor in the String class
            // to do that. Note that this code assumes the entire response can be retrieved
            // in one call to read(). You may NOT make that assumption in your finished
            // program.


            //Get DataInputStream of Array
            theSocket = new Socket(host, 80); // Port 80 is HTTP
            byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];//New byte array
            outgoing = theSocket.getOutputStream();
            incoming = new DataInputStream(theSocket.getInputStream());
            outgoing.write(packet.getBytes());
            int numBytes = incoming.read(buf);
            
            
            String filename = "textfile.txt";
            File theFile = new File(filename);

            if (args.length > 0) {
                filename = args[0];
            }

            if (theFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("It already exists. Contents will be overwritten");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Creating new file: " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());
                FileMake(args);
            }

            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
            String filePath = "/Users/bakya/Downloads/HW2/textfile.txt";
            writer.write(filePath.getBytes());
            writer.close();
            while (numBytes > 0) {
                System.out.println("Got: " + (new String(buf, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8")));
                host += args[0];         
                numBytes = incoming.read(buf);
            }

            theSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERR: Invalid File");
        }
    }
```

I want to print

```
Grabbing /wireshark-labs/INTRO-wireshark-file1.html from gaia.cs.umass.edu
Writing data to /Users/brichards/message.html
```

But my error says:

```
Sending packet to gaia.cs.umass.edu
It already exists. Contents will be overwritten
Got: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 25 Sep 2023 00:46:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.4.33 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.16.3
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to get what I want to print?

Comment: Log your string `packet`. Is it a valid HTTP request?

Comment: `packet = "Host: " + host + packet;` This is probably NOT what you want to send as an HTML request.  Just send "GET" string, not the rest of it.

Comment: I typed `packet = "Host: " + packet;` Still am getting that error.

Comment: Print out your string `packet`. Look at it. Compare it to a basic HTTP request example. Is what you've printed a valid HTTP request?

Comment: Why are you trying to reimplement HTTP? Java has libraries for that.

Comment: @Jorn I imagine this is a university assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```java
packet = "Host: " + host + packet;
```

It seems that this line is adding the `Host` header before the first line of an HTTP request (the `GET` in this case). If that intends to be valid HTTP the order should be inverted and `packet` should be first.